# Why do we ignore the real part of the transfer function while calculating Frequency response?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, control-theory

The transfer function obtained from the differential equation is a function of $s $ which $x + iy$, then why do we ignore the real part while finding out the frequency response magnitude and phase. Why is frequency response $H$ considered as $H(i\omega) $ instead as $ H(\sigma + i\omega)$?

Comment: I think the question is perfectly clear: the author wants to know why the frequency response is computed with imaginary arguments and not with complex arguments. My answer, given last week, answers exactly that point.

Comment: You meant “Why do we ignore the real part **of the argument** (or **of the independent variable**) of the transfer function?”

Comment: In brief, it’s because the presence of the sigma (real part) of the complex independent variable “s” corresponds to exponential factors in the time domain, which form transient terms in the output. But in the frequency response we’re interested in the sinusoidal steady-state response, thus the output shouldn’t have transient terms, thus the sigma should be zero (not present) in the transfer function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frequency response is the output of the system when its input is a sinusoid of the given frequency, which is the exponential of an imaginary quantity.

The rest are calculations: Laplace-transform the sinusoid, compute the output in the frequency domain, and verify that its phase and magnitude at a frequency $\omega$ can indeed be found by looking at $H(i \omega)$.

Comment: Pait, assuming you see this (OP is a few years old), would you mind adding a few details of the math?  I am having a hard time seeing how to proceed.

Comment: Suppose that the input $u(t) = \sin(\omega t)$. Compute the output as the Laplace anti-transform of $H(s) U(s)$. 

You will obtain a sinusoid with amplitude $|H(i \omega)|$ and phase $\arg (H(i \omega)$.

This is the basis for setting $ s = i \omega$ and identifying the frequency response of $H(s)$ with the complex quantity $H(i \omega)$.

Comment: Straightforward enough, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This might not be quite right but isn't it because when we set $x = 0$ i.e. $ s = iy$ then our Laplace transform is simply a fourier transform, and it is a fourier transform that takes us into the frequency domain and hence will give us the frequency response.